# Android Emulator hangs at android label even after large ram size provided

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, emulation, genymotion

My Android Studio emulator is not turning on. I tried to increase its size but nothing happened.
Please help me with this I am stuck with my work.
Thanks in advance

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you mention your system properties as well? Your RAM etc. And if you have an android device you can run your app on it too. Read more at https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html#RealDevice

Comment: you can use genymotion or other emulator

Comment: @Nishan I have 8 gb ram with dual boot windows and ubuntu i5 core intel,
It works fine on android devices.

Comment: @Hasmukhkachhatiya Thanx but  I used genymotion on windows but on ubuntu 14.04 the virtual box is gettint linux generic image header error thus, I am left with this option

Comment: have look this?http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/02/install-android-emulator-ubuntu-linux/

Comment: @Hasmukhkachhatiya Thanx, I have installed genymotion but it cannot find the virtualbox for the current os.So its not working.

Comment: @Banda Check if the hardware visualization is enabled on bios. And try to create the emulator with a lower display resolution.

Comment: @Nishan BIOS virtualization enabled,resolution lowered, restarted system, but no results

Comment: Usually it take some time to start the first time. Meanwhile try updating your Ubuntu display drivers. It appears to be some sort of a hardware problem.

Comment: @Nishan thanx for reply.... no improvement

Comment: Need of more help